# how to automatically detect and correct an abnormal period of data in a time serie using python

Tags: time-series, outliers

I am trying to find a method that allows me to automatically detect and correct abnormal periods of data points in a time series (a sequence of outliers). I've already tried ThymeBoost but it only corrects point outliers and not outlier periods.

Here is an example of a time series containing a period of outliers

the time series :

```
01/02/2018    288.000000
01/03/2018    332.000000
01/04/2018    277.000000
01/05/2018    233.000000
01/06/2018    204.000000
01/07/2018    216.000000
01/08/2018    175.000000
01/09/2018    218.000000
01/10/2018    413.000000
01/11/2018    416.000000
01/12/2018    151.000000
01/01/2019    224.000000
01/02/2019    563.000000
01/03/2019    413.000000
01/04/2019    238.000000
01/05/2019    343.000000
01/06/2019    176.000000
01/07/2019    533.103060
01/08/2019    230.000000
01/09/2019    364.000000
01/10/2019    324.000000
01/11/2019    437.000000
01/12/2019    738.000000
01/01/2020    619.000000
01/02/2020    728.000000
01/03/2020    506.000000
01/04/2020    500.000000
01/05/2020    886.000000
01/06/2020    892.000000
01/07/2020    268.000000
01/08/2020     32.000000
01/09/2020     45.000000
01/10/2020     51.000000
01/11/2020    373.000000
01/12/2020     61.000000
01/01/2021     73.000000
01/02/2021    779.000000
01/03/2021    584.718872
01/04/2021    614.000000
01/05/2021    489.000000
01/06/2021    534.000000
01/07/2021    455.000000
```

The plot:
[image]

I have also tried to use the seasonal decompose but it doesn't work since the series doesn't seem to have a seasonality

[image]